# remove a line with special character with pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to remove a line with special characters which is not prefixed with `\`.
Below are the special characters:

```
^$%.*+?!(){}[]|\
```

I need to check all the above special characters which is not prefixed with `\` in 2nd column.
I'm trying with `awk` to complete this, but no luck. I want the output as below.

input.txt

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
5,sm\(oke
6,ra\in
7,pla\\y
8,wor\+k
```

output.txt

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
6,ra\in
```

Comment: Your sample output does not match your description of the problem.  It appears that you trying to delete all lines that contain one of the special characters preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are simply looking for:

```
  awk '$2 !~ /\\[][|\\{}()!?+*.%$^]/' FS=,
```

This gives the desired output on the given input file, but does not at all match the description given in the question.

EDIT

Given the discussion in the comment section, it appears that the desired solution should output all lines that contain a special character, unless that character is preceded by a backslash.  Given that description, we must remove backslash from the list of special characters.  A (non-working, given for the purpose of description) solution is:

```
awk '$2 ~ /[^\\][][|{}()!?+*.%$^]/' FS=,
```

This simply matches any two character string in which the first is not a backslash and the 2nd is one of the characters `][|{}()!?+*.%$^`.  This fails because it does not catch the case in which a special character occurs as the first element of the string.  For that, we extend the regex so that the first character can be either the beginning of the string or anything that is not a backslash.

```
awk '$2 ~ /(^|[^\\])[][|{}()!?+*.%$^]/' FS=,
```

The reason we need to re-order the special characters is that `]` has a special meaning inside brackets (namely, it closed the brackets!) and it must be list first to avoid that meaning.  Similarly, `^` must *not* be first because it has a special meaning when it is the first member of a character class (it negates the class).  (The other characters don't matter; they just got reordered as a typographical accident.)

Comment: Inside a character class, you don't need to escape a pipe; it has no special meaning.

Comment: @Jonathan  Indeed.  It is interesting that my awk does not generate a warning on that.  It seems like `gawk` is *very* generous with that particular warning!

Comment: thanks @ William , but it is not giving the exact output if the input file contains row like `7,p+la\\y`

Comment: @Ganz Do you want that line to be output or not?  Your description does not match the examples you give, so it is difficult to know what you want.

Comment: Sorry @William the awk command fails when the 2nd column has 2 special charcters. i want these line as well in output.txt `7,p+la\\y`
few more examples `4,g)r(ap\+e` .

Comment: Stop just giving examples and describe what you want.  Are you saying that you want to output any line that contains a special character, unless that character is escaped with a backslash?  That is *very* different than removing lines with unescaped backslashes, and also very different from keeping lines that have 2 special characters.

Comment: i want the output has any line that contains a special character, unless that character is escaped with a backslash. sorry for providing more examples.

Answer (score 1):

One part of the trick is to put the special characters into a character class safely, remembering that `]`, `^` and `-` (not present in your list) have special rules associated with them in character classes.  Specifically, the `^` as first character negates the character class (so place it somewhere other than first), and the `]` character terminates the character class unless it is either first or second after a `^`.

Hence, you want:

```
awk '/\\[]^$%.*+?!(){}[\\|]/ { next } { print }' input.txt
```

The complex (ghastly) regex matches a backslash followed by one of the special characters; the action is `next` to skip that line.  The `{ print }` (which could also be written `1` or any other true value) prints those lines which are not eliminated by the regex.

Example output

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
6,ra\in
```

You can refine the processing to ignore the first field and so on as in [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627090/15168), which does the reordering of the characters in the list substantially the same way I did, but without explaining why.

```
awk -F, '$2 !~ /\\[]^$%.*+?!(){}[\\|]/ { print }' input.txt
```

Comment: thanks @Jonathan, but it is not giving the exact output if the input file contains row like `7,p+la\\y`

Comment: What's your required output when there is a special character without a backslash and another with a backslash?  Your test data and description does not cover that case.

Comment: Sorry @Jonathan the awk command fails when the 2nd column has 2 special charcters(one is with backslash another without backslash). i want these line as well in output.txt `7,p+la\\y`
few more examples `4,g)r(ap\+e` . since  one more special character is present in the column without a backslash. Sorry i missed to inculde that in description.